# I keep getting a value error in the train test split function despite trying to adjust the params

Tags: pandas, train-test-split

Here is what I keep getting and I can't figure out why. I've adjusted the params but to no avail.

```
tst=[list of features]
X=[tst]
y=[pd.get_dummies(tst['class'],drop_first=True)]
​
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,train_size=.75)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-148-63b61d820602> in <module>
----> 1 X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,train_size=.75)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in train_test_split(*arrays, **options)
   2129     n_samples = _num_samples(arrays[0])
   2130     n_train, n_test = _validate_shuffle_split(n_samples, test_size, train_size,
-> 2131                                               default_test_size=0.25)
   2132 
   2133     if shuffle is False:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in _validate_shuffle_split(n_samples, test_size, train_size, default_test_size)
   1812             'resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the '
   1813             'aforementioned parameters.'.format(n_samples, test_size,
-> 1814                                                 train_size)
   1815         )
   1816 

ValueError: With n_samples=1, test_size=None and train_size=0.75, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.
```

Thank you.

Comment: what is `tst` ?

Comment: It's a variable that is a list of features.

Comment: thats one of the problem, `X` must be a numpy array of size `m x n`